# jquery ajax parse error in asp.net vb.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

```
<script src="Script/jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var msgbox = $("#status");
                $("#Button1").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/HelloWorld",
                        data: "{'args':'Hello World'}",

                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            msgbox.html(msg.d);
                        }

                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
            <span id="status"></span>
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

_Default class

```
    Imports System.Web.Services

    Partial Class _Default
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
        Public Shared Function HelloWorld(ByVal args As String) As String
            Return args 
        End Function
    End Class
```

When i run the code above..it popup erro message "parseerror". How to return the string value/json value?any value also can..as long as can return value..thx..

Comment: Can you post what the response is? Depending on how the response is formatted, that could be causing issues or just not returning what you think at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your success function is not parsing the returned value as Json, so .d is causing the error

```
success: function (msg) {
                        msgbox.html(msg.d);
                    }
```

try

```
success: function (msg) {
                        var model = JSON.Parse(msg);
                        msgbox.html(model.args);
                    }
```